# Smarty php display only a particular array index

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I need to display `{$user.unread}` in this format in my *.tpl file without any for loop so that only the number 3 shows up.

my php files has `$user = array('unread' => 3);` what should my smarty assign and php array codes be?

I'm doing this to integrate design with smarty codes, without the need to connect up with the database. Hence, `{$user.unread}` has to be the format to call "3" or any number in the *.tpl file, but in the php file I can define a static array and call the smarty accordingly. I'm unsure of the syntax in the php file to define this static array and define the smarty assign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just assign the array to the smarty variable. It should work the way you intended.

in php:

```
$user = array('unread' => 3);
$smarty->assign('user',$user)
```

in tpl:

```
{$user.unread}
```

Comment: Thanks! Similarly, how would my php file array and smarty assign codes be for a tpl file with `{$data.user.name}` ? Thanks!

Comment: @Sayanee, that would be a 2-D array like so $data = array('user'=>array('name'=>'John Smith')); $smarty->assign('data',$data);